# Why am I getting an error in this create table script?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm attempting to write my first php/mysql page and am running into a SQL syntax error I can't find the cause of.

The error is as following:

> Unable to create domain suggestions table. Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY_KEY, domain TEXT, author TEXT, submitdate DATE NOT NULL ) DE' at line 2

```
CREATE TABLE domainsuggestions(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY_KEY,
    domain TEXT,
    author TEXT,
    submitdate DATE NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your *CREATE TABLE* statement, it should be `PRIMARY KEY` with a **space** instead of `PRIMARY_KEY` that contains an **underscore**.

#### Solution:

Remove the *underscore* from `PRIMARY_KEY`.

#### Corrected script:

```
CREATE TABLE domainsuggestions
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    domain TEXT,
    author TEXT,
    submitdate DATE NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

#### Demo:

[**Click here to view the working CREATE TABLE script in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/000a1)